# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found while trying to edit null value in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a edit function to edit the existing value in database in laravel.a

Whenever i click on edit function(button) which has null value (default value is set to null in sql when there is no data provided) in it, it shows an error:

*Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.*

But when I click on edit which has value, the function works correctly.

What should be done in this situation?

Controller :

```
public function showuserseditform($id)
{
    $wallet = Wallet::find($id);

    return view('Admin.Wallets.editUserWallet')->with('wallet', $wallet);

}
```

Edit Page Functions:

```
<td> 
    <a href="{{ route('userwallet.edit',['id' => $wallet['walletUsers']['walletid'] ]) }}" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Edit ">
        <i class="la la-edit"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="{{ route('userwallet.destroy', ['id' => $wallet['walletUsers']['walletid'] ]) }}" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Delete ">
        <i class="la la-trash"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Edit Form :

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="{{ route('userwallet.update',['id' => $wallet->walletid ]) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-body">
        <h4 class="form-section"><i class="la la-eye"></i> Wallet Details</h4>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" value="{{ $wallet->walletUserId->name  }}" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Name" name="name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Wallet Balance</label>
                    <input type="text" id="text" value="{{ $wallet->balance }}" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Email"
                           name="balance">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions right">
        <a href="{{ route('user.wallet') }}" class="btn btn-warning mr-1">
            <i class="ft-x"></i> Cancel
        </a>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="la la-check-square-o"></i> Save
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Route for edit :

```
Route::get('/admin/wallet/edit/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'WalletController@showuserseditform', 
    'as' => 'userwallet.edit'
]);
```

Kindly guide to edit field even if its null !

Comment: are you trying to access with vhost?
if you are probably about DocumentRoot.

Comment: the database is situated in aws, but i am accessing the database locally. !

Comment: change route to `Route::get('/admin/wallet/edit/{id}','WalletController@showuserseditform')->name('userwallet.edit');`

Comment: Nope, tried ! getting same error !

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Route::get('/admin/wallet/edit/{id?}', [
  'uses' => 'WalletController@showuserseditform', 
  'as' => 'userwallet.edit'
]);


public function showuserseditform($id=null)
{

    $view_data = [];


    $view_data['wallet'] = $id ? Wallet::find($id) : null;


    return view('Admin.Wallets.editUserWallet', $view_data);

}
```

In addition, probably in the template you will have to add terms that like `$wallet == null`, do not let it show data from the model.

Comment: I think @Arvindh wanted to be able to see the view regardless of if `$id` had been passed. This would mean they would be redirected with an error message.

Comment: All you need to do is add a question mark to it rout 
and modify functions accordingly

`Route::get('/admin/wallet/edit/{id?}', [
    'uses' => 'WalletController@showuserseditform', 
    'as' => 'userwallet.edit'
]);`

Comment: Adding the `?` will have mean the url parameter on the route is optional. However, within the `showusereditform()` method, the first check will return the user to the original page if the `id` of the `wallet` is not passed. What is being asked in the question is how to return the `editUserWallet` `view` regardless if the `id` is passed or not.

Comment: I wrote that you must then modify this condition .. eg. `if(!$id){ $wallet = null; }else{ $wallet = Wallet::find($id);}` But there may also be a problem in the template, because you can reference the model, in which case the model will be null.